# codeigniter Object not found! 404 error

Tags: codeigniter

hi everyone im new to php frameworks development at all, and i can't make this code run please help me im using xampp

my welcome controller

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

public function index()
{

    $this->load->view('home');

}
}
```

home view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CTS - home</title>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#C0C0C0" style="height: 226px">

<div class="auto-style1" style="height: 118px">
    <img alt="" height="126" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?    >/IMG/YUC.png" style="float: left" width="147">
    <center><h1 style="height: 39px; width: 696px">Cooperative Training Management     System</h1></center>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<div class="auto-style1">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('') ?>users/login">
    <img alt="YUC Employee" height="410" src="<?php echo $this->config-    >item('base_url'); ?>/IMG/employee.png" width="139">
    </a>
    <img alt="trainer" height="410" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?    >/IMG/Trainer.png" width="145">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('') ?>users/login">
    <img alt="Student" height="410" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?    >/IMG/student.png" width="129">
    </a>
    <h3>Employee&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp        ;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Trainer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp    ;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Student</h3>
</div>
<hr>
<p align="right">Page generated in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the second controller users

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Controller 
{

    function login()
    {
        $data['error']=0;
        if($_POST){
            $this->load->model('user');
            $username=$this->input->post('username',ture);
            $password=$this->input->post('password',true);
            $user=$this->user->login($username,$password);
            if(!$user){
                $data['error']=1;
            }else{
                $this->session->set_userdata('userID',$user['userID']);
                redirect(base_url().'home');
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('login');

    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destory();
        redirect(base_url().'home');
    }
}
```

and this is the model user

```
<?php

class User extends CI_Model 
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');  
    }

    function login($username,$password)
    {

        $where=array(
                        'username'=>$username,
                        'password'=>sha1($password)
                    );
        $this->db->select()->from('s_users')->where($where);
        $querh=$this->db->get();
        return $querh->first_row('array');
    }
}
```

and this is the login view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CTS - Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#C0C0C0" style="height: 98px">

<div class="auto-style1" style="height: 118px">
    <img alt="" height="126" src="YUC.png" style="float: left" width="147">
    <center><h1 style="height: 113px; width: 696px">Cooperative Training Management     System</h1></center>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<div class="auto-style1">

<fieldset name="Group1">
    <legend align="left"><h1>Login</h1></legend>
    <?php if($error==1){ ?>
    <p>Your Username / Password did not match.</p>
    <? } ?>
    <form action="<?=base_url()?>users/login" method="post" style="height: 96px">

        <label>Username </label><input name="Text1" type="text">
        <br>
        <label>Password</label> <input name="Password1" type="password">
        <br><br>
        <input name="Login" style="width: 96px" type="submit" value="Login">

    </form>

</fieldset>
</div>
<hr>
<p align="right">Page generated in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly you want here? What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: Please paste the full error message returned

Comment: keep Your point precise at paste the error

Answer (score 2):

Maybe url is incorrect.

```
    http://localhost/projectfolder/index.php/controller/method
```

in ur case:

```
    http://localhost/yourprojectfolder/index.php/users/login
```

Replace "projectfolder", "controller", "method" with yours. Make sure your file name for Users Controller is "users.php"

Answer (score 0):

use

```
base_url();
```

instead of

```
$this->config->item('base_url');
```

if you want to keep a config param use this :

```
$this->config->config['base_url'];
```

also this is not ok:

```
<?php echo site_url('') ?>users/login
```

use it like this:

```
<?php echo site_url('users/login') ?>
```

In the end check if you have `views/home.php` file

can't see anyother error in your code

then be sure you have:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and use this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: mmmm not working my dear same thing with me i cant find any other error

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16

Comment: by the way the first controller works but when i try to move to users controller i cant

Comment: @user2637286 ok do you use **.htaccess**? can you post it please? can you also post your **config/config.php** and **config/routes.php** files please?

Comment: the problem was index.php in the url see my .htaccess

Comment: @user2637286 ok understood, just follow my last directives you'll get no problems with. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you Using WAMP server then open "httpd.conf" file, search 
  "**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**" and remove # which in the start of the same line..
and 
 ***restart your WAMP Server***

Then add this code to your .htaccess file which is in the codeigniter folder (if not create it in the folder's **root)**:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Answer (score 0):

check for URL which call functions
for e.g

```
Correct URL
http://127.0.0.1/mysites/site1_ci_bootstrap/index.php/welcome/home
```

May be your URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1/mysites/site1_ci_bootstrap/welcome/home
```

NOTE : Initially always need to mention "index.php" into the path which redirect to main class "welcome", To remove "index.php" put .htaccess script into root folder, google several htaccess script you find one.